# Registering different UnitOfWorks per each module for a generic CommandHandler using structuremap

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, structuremap, unit-of-work

I'm using CQRS pattern in my recent project, and used EF code first in my DAL, so I defined some generic `CommandHandlers` to do Insert/Update/Delete:

```
public class InsertCommandHandler<TEntity> : ICommandHandler<InsertCommandParameter<TEntity>>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot<TEntity>, new()
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public InsertCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public void Handle(InsertCommandParameter<TEntity> parameter)
    {
        var entity = parameter.Entity;
        _uow.Repository<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }
}

public interface ICommandParameter
{
}

public abstract class  BaseEntityCommandParameter<T> : ICommandParameter
    where T :  BaseEntity, new()
{
    public T Entity { get; set; }

    protected BaseEntityCommandParameter()
    {
        Entity = new T();
    }
}
public  class InsertCommandParameter<T> : BaseEntityCommandParameter<T> where T :  class, new()
{
}
```

As you see I injected the `IUnitOfWork` to the `InsertCommandHandler` constructor.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot<T>,new ();
    void Commit();
}
```

I used `Structuremap 3` as my `IoC Container`, So I defined following conversion to resolve `ICommandHandler`s for each `BaseEntity` types(using [custom registration conventions for partially closed types](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/01/07/advanced-structuremap-custom-registration-conventions-for-partially-closed-types/)):

```
public class CRUDCommandRegistrationConvention : StructureMap.Graph.IRegistrationConvention
{
    private static readonly
    Type _openHandlerInterfaceType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>);
    private static readonly
    Type _openInsertCommandType = typeof(InsertCommandParameter<>);
    private static readonly
    Type _openInsertCommandHandlerType = typeof(InsertCommandHandler<>);
    private static readonly
    Type _openUpdateCommandType = typeof(UpdateCommandParameter<>);
    private static readonly
    Type _openUpdateCommandHandlerType = typeof(UpdateCommandHandler<>);
    private static readonly
    Type _openDeleteCommandType = typeof(DeleteCommandParameter<>);
    private static readonly
    Type _openDeleteCommandHandlerType = typeof(DeleteCommandHandler<>);



    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof(BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            if (type.GetInterfaces()
                .Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() 
                    == typeof(IAggregateRoot<>)))
            {
                Type closedInsertCommandType = _openInsertCommandType.MakeGenericType(type);
                Type closedInsertCommandHandlerType = _openInsertCommandHandlerType.MakeGenericType(type);
                Type closedUpdateCommandType = _openUpdateCommandType.MakeGenericType(type);
                Type closedUpdateCommandHandlerType = _openUpdateCommandHandlerType.MakeGenericType(type);
                Type closedDeleteCommandType = _openDeleteCommandType.MakeGenericType(type);
                Type closedDeleteCommandHandlerType = _openDeleteCommandHandlerType.MakeGenericType(type);

                Type insertclosedHandlerInterfaceType = _openHandlerInterfaceType.MakeGenericType(closedInsertCommandType);
                Type updateclosedHandlerInterfaceType = _openHandlerInterfaceType.MakeGenericType(closedUpdateCommandType);
                Type deleteclosedHandlerInterfaceType = _openHandlerInterfaceType.MakeGenericType(closedDeleteCommandType);

                registry.For(insertclosedHandlerInterfaceType).Use(closedInsertCommandHandlerType);
                    registry.For(updateclosedHandlerInterfaceType).Use(closedUpdateCommandHandlerType);
                    registry.For(deleteclosedHandlerInterfaceType).Use(closedDeleteCommandHandlerType);
            }
    }
}
```

And used it in my CompositionRoot:

```
    public static class ApplicationConfiguration
{
    public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(s =>
            {
                s.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
                s.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(Order));
                s.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(FindOrderByIdQueryHandler));
                s.WithDefaultConventions();
                x.For(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
                    .Use(typeof(EfUnitOfWork<SaleDBContext>))
                    .Named("SaleDBContext")
                    .SetLifecycleTo((Lifecycles.Singleton));
                s.Convention<CRUDCommandRegistrationConvention>();

            });

        });

        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

I registered `EfUnitOfWork<SaleDBContext>` for `IUnitOfWork`, but I want to use separate `DbContext` per each module in my solution(`Bounded context`). For example my sale module has its own `DbContext`, HR module has its own `DbContext` and etc, and above registration conversion, only register `EfUnitOfWork<SaleDBContext>` as my `IUnitOfWork`.

I have some modules(Solution Folders in Visual Studio) in my solution and each module has 3 layer(3 class library projects):
My modules has following structure(each module has 3 assemblies) for example:

```
 SaleModule: 
 ----Application 
 ----Domain (Entities , ...) //Order, Customer,...
 ----DAL (DbContext ,...) //SaleDbContext

 HRModule: 
 ----Application 
 ----Domain (Entities , ...) // Employee, OrganizationUnit, ...
 ----DAL (DbContext ,...)//HRDbContext

 InfrastructureModule: 
 ----Application (ICommandHandler,IQueryHandler,...)
 ----Domain 
 ----DAL
```

The `InsertCommandHandler<T>` puts in Infrastructure Module.

When I use the `InsertCommanHandler<T>` I want it uses corresponding module's `DbContext` as `IUnitOfWork`. for example, I want the `InsertCommandHandler<Order>` uses `SaleDbContext` as it's `IUnitOfWork` and `InsertCommandHandler<Employee>` uses `HRDbContext` as it's `IUnitOfWork`.

[**UPDATED**]

This is a sample of cunsumers code that IoC containar should provide `SaleDbContext` for `Consumer1` and `HRDbContext` for `Consumer2`:

```
public class Consumer1
{
    ICommandHandler<InsertCommandParameter<Order>> _insertCommandHandler;
    public Consumer1(ICommandHandler<InsertCommandParameter<Order>> insertCommandHandler)
    {
       _insertCommandHandler = insertCommandHandler;
    }
    public void DoInsert()
    {
        var command = new InsertCommandParameter<Order>();
        command.Entity = new Order(){
                                       Number = 'ord-01',
                                       // other properties
                                    };
        insertCommandHandler.Handle(command); //this query handler should use SaleDbContext

    }
}

public class Consumer2
{
    ICommandHandler<InsertCommandParameter<Employee>> _insertCommandHandler;
    public Consumer2(ICommandHandler<InsertCommandParameter<Employee>> insertCommandHandler)
    {
       _insertCommandHandler = insertCommandHandler;
    }
    public void DoInsert()
    {
        var command = new InsertCommandParameter<Employee>();
        command.Entity = new Employee(){
                                       EmployeeNumber = 'Emp1',
                                       // other properties
                                    };
        insertCommandHandler.Handle(command); //this query handler should use HRDbContext

    }
}
```

How could I do that in my composition root using `StructureMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `IUnitOfWork` generic as in `IUnitOfWork<TConnection>`. This allows each `Repository` to stipulate which `UnitOfWork` it requires, ideally using constructor injection, e.g.

```
public class InsertCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<Order>
{
    public InsertCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork<SalesDbContext> salesUnitOfWork)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, you probably don't want to reference the `DbContext` in each handler so you should define an abstraction to avoid such a dependency.

Start with a simple interface that all `DbContext` wrapper classes will implement

```
public interface IConnection
{
    DbContext Context { get; }
}
```

Update `IUnitOfWork` accordingly

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<TConnection> where TConnection : IConnection { }
```

Here's an example wrapper

```
public class SalesConnection : IConnection
{
    private readonly DbContext context;

    public SalesConnection()
    {
        this.context = new SalesDbContext();
    }

    public DbContext Context { get { return this.context; } }
}
```

And here's what the updated command handler will look like

```
public class InsertCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<Order>
{
    public InsertCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork<SalesConnection> salesUnitOfWork)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

The logical thing to do for common handlers is to have one per logical domain (i.e. per `DbContext`), for example `SalesInsertCommandHandler`, `HRInsertCommandHandler`

```
public class SalesInsertCommandHandler<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    public SalesInsertCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork<SalesConnection> unitOfWork)
    {

    }
}
```

This adheres to the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle and gives you extra flexibility when you come to decorate your concerns with different aspects (tracing, retry logic etc.)

All command handlers can of course inherit from a single common (abstract) command handler.

```
public abstract class CommandHandler<TConnection, TCommand> :
     ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TConnection : IConnection

{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork<TConnection> unitOfWork;

    public CommandHandler(IUnitOfWork<TConnection> unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}

public class SalesInsertCommandHandler<TCommand> : 
    CommandHandler<SalesConnection, TCommand>
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks qujck, but if I use your solution, I have to define OrderInsertCommandHandler,EmployeeInsertCommandHandler,... separately for each entity, but I want use the generic InsertCommandHandler<> for my entities, I updated my question, plz see the consumer class.

Comment: I think It works, but I'm looking for a solution with one single `InsertCommandHandler<TCommand>` class if possible.